# Do audio files converted to raw retain previous sampling rate?

Tags: php, linux, audio, audio-streaming, sox

OK. I'm trying to learn about audio and compression.  I have a fundamental question that I haven't found the answer to yet scouring the internet.

I know that there are self describing formats with header information. If I convert different files into "raw" format with sox, am I wrong in  thinking that gives them the same number of "channels" and "sample rate"?

I guess I was thinking that raw would be the great "neutralizer." Is this not the case? Like you could treat all files as if they were the same if they were in raw format?

Wikipedia says...

> RAW Audio format or just RAW Audio is
>   a computer format for storing
>   uncompressed audio in raw form.
>   Comparable to WAV or AIFF in size, RAW
>   Audio file does not include any header
>   information (sampling rate, bit depth,
>   endian, or number of channels). Data
>   can be written in PCM, IEEE 754 or
>   ASCII.[citation needed]

There is also some good information on file format in general at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format

**Clarification**
I need to concatenate mp3 files that may start out with different numbers of channels and sampling rates.  I don't honestly know how many channels I want to end up with.  I am trying to combine the different files with sox.  However, sox needs the files be in the same file format.  So, I was hoping to get them in the "same file format" meaning the same number of channels and sampling rate.

However, now it seems that raw might just these two items but remove the self describing header information? In other words, an mp3 file converted to raw, retains the same properties (sampling rate and number of channels)?

Comment: I think you want to use Lossless Compression.  What do you mean by neutralizer?

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear.  I'm being brutally honest about what I DON'T understand....

Comment: Ok take internet radio streaming, in those you make a playlist with different formats and bitrate... but you want to stream lets say mp3 @ bitrate 128Kbps and sampling fq 44000Hz.  An example like that could fit your purposes? if so I can further explain

Comment: Let's say my friend and I want to piece together interviews (from command line) into a single mp3 file.  MY friend thought, hey, it's just words, so let's do one channel and 44000Hz.  I am worried about losing quality so I do two channels for my interview.  Summary: We have an intro text for this radio show which might have some other mp3 compression.  We're set on this (for whatever reason) and we want to combine the various files to make a new file.  Since we are geeks, we think we need to do it all in command line linux.  We want to combine intro and two interviews to make a new mp3 file.

Comment: Can audacity be done in the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. Extract the data from each mp3-file and convert it to a WAV file (You'll have to find a mp3 decoder for that).
2. Convert the WAV-files so they all have the same WAV format (what ever format you like, format meaning: sample rate, bit resolution, etc.).
3. Concatenate the files to one WAV-file.
4. Convert the resulting file back to mp3 (mp3 encoder needed).

RAW-files are the same as WAV-files, only that they have no header that tells you the format. So you can completely forget about RAW-files unless you happen to know the audio format of the file anyway, and therefore don't need that header information.

Comment: I had some luck converting to raw format of "au" with FFMPEG, however it then said header size 24 is too small when I converted to mp3... Would that be b/c the raw file has no header at all?

Comment: AU is not RAW. Check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_file_format. Apparently AU has a header of 24 Byte(?). RAW has no header at all.

Comment: OK, so you think, go with wav.  I can try to adjust for that tonight.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any "standard" for raw audio files.  They can be encoded any number of ways, with different bit rates and channel counts.  If you're trying to find a way to convert audio between formats, this is not the answer for you.

Comment: :( That is what I'm trying to do.  Sox can't concatenate files with different bit rates.  So you need to get the files to have the SAME bit rate and number of channels before you can concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

MP3 files can be directly concatenated even with varying rates, &c.  You may have other reasons for wanting raw data or wav (raw + header), but you can do this without a decode/encode step.

---

I stand corrected.  A lot of the MP3 files I manage via back-end programming (scripts) indeed vary their frame headers, bit rates, et cetera.  We then stream it through through another commercial product BUT APPARENTLY said product respects each and every header!

When I tried the same input stream through Google Chrome as well as QuickTime it appears as only the very first header is respected and assumed throughout the whole file!  Who'da thunk?

So I learned a big lesson here, thank goodness the streamer must pre-flight the MP3 stream!  In this case I think decoding to "raw" with the maximum # of channels that you expect in the output is the way to go, then you can downmix to the # of channels needed upon encoding.

Comment: Xepoch, thank you for taking the time to respond.  Do you have a command line tool in mind that would achieve this?

Comment: The ubiquitous `cat` or `type` should do it. :)

Comment: Cat doesn't do it b/c it isn't sophisticated enough.  You can have different sampling rates, there is conflicting ID3 information, channels, etc.

Comment: I started off using cat.  It won't work unless the files start out with all matching data and even then you get varying results depending on which audio player you are using.  I was hoping that cat would have worked... Many hours later....

Comment: @Scott - see my update above.  You can also use `dd` to pull the frames in groups. Ex for a 64kbps CBR `dd if=foo.mp3 bs=576 count=192 of=cut.mp3` to pull ~5 seconds out.

Comment: OK, I must admit that I have not tried "DD" nor do I know anything about it.  I will make sure to look at this for at least part of the solution. Thank you.